# Unable to login to heroku without authentication code

Tags: heroku

I'm unable to login to heroku because of Entering the code generated by my authenticator app, actually I have deleted my authenticator app so I'm unable to recover it.
I have a paid subscription on heroku so I don't want to waste it so is there any way to login via email?

Thanks.

I tried to login but it still asked for authentication app code :(